# Android TV get current source

Tags: android, television, android-tv

I am trying to develop an application for Android TV which will be notified when the user switches to a certain source (e.g. HDMI). Is there any listener/callback/broadcast for source switch or any method to be run from the background which returns the current source on the TV ?
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputManager.html)

Regards